# Web scraping with R with scroll down

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am looking to download the first two columns ("GAS DAY STARTED ON" and "GAS IN STORAGE) from the following URL:

https://agsi.gie.eu/#/historical/eu

The default period is set to "LAST MONTH" and I would need "ALL".

Is someone able to tell me what package I can use to achieve this type of task?
There is also a free API, but I did not manage to get far with that either.

Grateful for every input!
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: use selenium but it easier to use API no other download required

Comment: thanks! just to make sure i understand you, if i use the API, i dont need any packages? thanks again!

Comment: you need `jsonlite` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to steer you closer to the API path. If you have an API key you can (but you shouldn't) pass it directly to the following function. You *should* put it in your `~/.Renviron` as:

```
AGSI_KEY=thekeytheygaveyou
```

and restart your R session. It will then be used automagically.

The following function takes start/end dates

```
get_agsi_data <- function(start, end, agsi_api_key = Sys.getenv("AGSI_KEY")) {

  start[1] <- as.character(as.Date(start[1]))
  end[1] <- as.character(as.Date(end)[1])

  httr::GET(
    url = "https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/eu", # NOTE THE HARDCODING FOR eu
    httr::add_headers(`x-key` = agsi_api_key),
    httr::user_agent("user@example.com") # REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res) # warns when API issues

  out <- httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

  out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)

  sapply(out$info, function(x) { # the info element is an ugly list so we need to make it better
    if (length(x)) {
      x <- paste0(x, collapse = "; ") 
    } else {
      NA_character_
    }
  }) -> info

  out$info <- info

  readr::type_convert(
    df = out,
    col_types = cols(
      status = col_character(),
      gasDayStartedOn = col_date(format = ""),
      gasInStorage = col_double(),
      full = col_double(),
      trend = col_double(),
      injection = col_double(),
      withdrawal = col_double(),
      workingGasVolume = col_double(),
      injectionCapacity = col_double(),
      withdrawalCapacity = col_double()
    )
  ) -> out

  class(out) <- c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")

  out

}

xdf <- get_agsi_data("2018-06-01", "2018-10-01")

xdf
## # A tibble: 2,880 x 11
##    status gasDayStartedOn gasInStorage  full trend injection withdrawal workingGasVolume injectionCapacity
##  * <chr>  <date>                 <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>
##  1 E      2018-11-19              918.  86.1 -0.41      343.      4762.            1067.            11469.
##  2 E      2018-11-18              923.  86.5 -0.22      534.      2841.            1067.            11469.
##  3 E      2018-11-17              925.  86.7 -0.2       649.      2796.            1067.            11469.
##  4 E      2018-11-16              927.  86.9 -0.24      492.      3014.            1067.            11469.
##  5 E      2018-11-15              930.  87.1 -0.16      503.      2210.            1067.            11469.
##  6 E      2018-11-14              931.  87.3 -0.1       605.      1682.            1067.            11469.
##  7 E      2018-11-13              933.  87.4 -0.07      651.      1438.            1067.            11469.
##  8 E      2018-11-12              933.  87.5 -0.05      833.      1391.            1067.            11468.
##  9 E      2018-11-11              934.  87.5  0.09     1607.       659.            1067.            11478.
## 10 E      2018-11-10              933.  87.4  0.06     1458.       796.            1067.            11478.
## # ... with 2,870 more rows, and 2 more variables: withdrawalCapacity <dbl>, info <chr>
```

`eu` is hardcoded but it shld be straightforward to augment for other API endpoints:

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks for your help! I get the following error message when I run the code though:  Error in readr::type_convert(df = out, col_types = cols(status = col_character(),  : 
  is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE

Comment: i also noticed something.. after line 18 - out <- httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8") - i created tmp <<- out which results in "{\"error\":\"access denied\"}". could that mean that i am not connected to the API at all? thanks again!!

Comment: aye. it means you didn't specify the API key or have a bad API key

Comment: HMM. WEIRD.. I USED THE FOLLOWING STRUCTURE                                                                                         library("readr")

AGSI_KEY="0bf8e8a083be3e9326eb0dd04e68fxxx" #AMENDED KEY

get_agsi_data <- function(start, end, agsi_api_key = Sys.getenv("AGSI_KEY")) {
  
  start[1] <- as.character(as.Date(start[1]))
  etc...

Comment: oh, i missed an important step as it seems. i just ran the key line at the start of the script.. making myself familiar now with Renviron. thanks again for your patience :)

Comment: APIs can take a bit of getting used to if you haven't worked with them before. And even the best ones can take alot of trial and error. Your persistence is commendable!